# how to Deploy salesforce app from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, salesforce, force.com

Ok so i'm new to salesforce.I started by installing the force IDE from `http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation`
I have a salesforce application code that i want to deploy in my salesforce org.
I have imported the app into eclipse but don't know what to do next.
Can any one guide me or provide any useful links to achieve what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the resources you want to deploy and select `Force.com/Deploy to server...` in the context menu.

More flexible way to deploy is [described here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Deploy_Force.com_Applications_Faster).

More links could be found in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/647/2812).

Comment: but i don't see any such as Force.com/Deploy to Server.For ur info i just installed Force IDE thats it.And imported a salesforce app.Do i need to configure it or some thing.

Comment: Try to point force.com perspective: `Window -> Open perspective -> Other...` select `Force.com (default)`. After that `Force.com` should apper at context menu.

Comment: What kind of installation package did you use from http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation ?

Comment: Also check that you run installed Force IDE not the different instance of Eclipse.

Comment: i installed the standalone application windows installer 64 bit on my system from http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation. after installation its stated that "Once you have completed installation, go to Help | Software and Workspace Center and click the "Apply" button in the dashboard tab." but i didn't find anything of that sort in the force IDE

Comment: I was installed the same version of IDE few hours ago. Thats how it looks for me (Software and Workspace Center and Perspective windows): http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/2599/forceide.png Looks like something wrong with your installation. Try to reinstall it.